# How to make AWS S3 request retryable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Sometimes when I download multiple files from S3 bucket using node sdk, the request will timeout for one of the downloads. I would like for the request to just retry to attempt to download again.

The json error response says `retryable: false`.

Is there a way I can configure it to be `true`?

Here is the error:

```
{ TimeoutError: Connection timed out after 480000ms
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:83:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (domain.js:421:20)
    at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:703:34)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (domain.js:421:20)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:396:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:466:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:267:5)
  message: 'Connection timed out after 480000ms',
  code: 'TimeoutError',
  time: 2019-04-01T17:58:41.010Z,
  region: 'us-west-2',
  hostname: 'bucket-name',
  retryable: false,
  statusCode: 200,
  retryDelay: 129.76727762396757 }
```

Comment: can you share your code ?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure of how you are using the resources as you didn't share your code, but this might help you.

```js
// setting retries
var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01', maxRetries:10});
```

[S3 sdk documentation - maxRetries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#maxRetries-property)